# Required Date Time Picker has always "aria-invalid=false"

Tags: xpages

I'm not sure if I am missing out a very simple thing. Normally, XPages maintain "aria-required" and "aria-invalid" attributes for validation.

However, for DateTime Picker (standard one), it's always `aria-invalid="false"`.

Here is a simple test I have used in Domino 9.0.1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="TestForm"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panel1">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <xp:panel id="panel1">
        <xp:inputText id="inputText1" required="true">
            <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
            <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
            </xp:this.converter>
        </xp:inputText>
        <xp:messages id="messages1"></xp:messages>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Generated HTML before the button clicked contains:

```
<input type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" id="view:_id1:inputText1" value="">
```

After clicking, I can see Messages component has been aggregated but aria-invalid is false.

```
<input type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" id="view:_id1:inputText1" value="">
```

*(I removed dojo stuff wrapping the input)*

Comment: Where's your validator?

Comment: Tim, there is required="true"... Before you ask, I tried formal required validator too :)

Comment: Those aria attributes are usually associated with with accessibility helping web applications more usable to people with disabilities. I don't think regular validation is effected here but I've asked our experts within the team to confirm this.

Comment: Validation is working OK. It just doesn't generate aria attributes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found that this problem is not related to XPages.

XPages provides the `aria-invalid` attribute correctly if validation fails. However, dojo controls automatically change it during rendering. So it's not possible unless you inject a correction into Dojo component rendering code.